# Filtering with AJAX in Django

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, filtering

In my Django project, I have a basic view where I pass all instances of the Article model and then display them in an HTML template with a for loop. I also have a Topic model, so I display all topics as buttons, also with a for loop. My goal is to filter articles by clicking a specific Topic button, so if I click "Politics," for example, then only articles connected to the "Politics" topic will be displayed instead of all articles. I want to use an AJAX request for this, but I do not have experience with it, so I am having some problems figuring out how to achieve my goal.

Here is my view. I am trying to do AJAX in the same view, but I am not sure if this is correct because, in most cases that I saw, a separate view was created:

```
def main_view(request):
    all_articles = Article.objects.all()[::-1]
    top_articles = all_articles[:10]
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    if request.is_ajax():
        topic_name = request.GET.get('topic_name')
        all_articles = Article.objects.filter(topics=topic_name)
        return JsonResponse({'all_articles': all_articles})

    return render(request, "mainapp/main_refactor.html", {"all_articles": all_articles, "top_articles": top_articles, "topics": topics})
```

Simplified HTML template:

```
{% for topic in topics %}
    <button class="topic-button" data-url="{% url 'mainapp:filter_articles' topic.name %}"
            data-topic-name="{{ topic.name }}">{{ topic.name }}</button>
{% endfor %}
<section id="article-list" class="new-articles">
    {% for article in all_articles %}
        {{ article.body }}
    {% endfor %}
```

And AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.topic-button').click(function () {
        var topicName = $(this).data('topic-name');
        var url = $(this).data('url');  // tried to add separate URLs for each Topic filtering, but abandoned it for now, so everything is in one view
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {'topic_name': topicName},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response + " I have no idea what to code here");
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Above code is where I am now. It would be perfect to have seperate view for ajax request with url "/topic/str:topic_name". Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate endpoint for the filter

```
def filter_articles(request):
    topic_name = request.GET.get('topic_name')
    if topic_name:
        articles = Article.objects.filter(topics__name=topic_name)
        return JsonResponse({'all_articles': articles})  # Serialize articles for JSON response
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'No topic provided'})
```

Url

```
path('filter_articles/', views.filter_articles, name='filter_articles')
```

For html part you can do it like this

```
{% for topic in topics %}
    <button class="topic-button" data-topic-name="{{ topic.name }}">{{ topic.name }}</button>
{% endfor %}
<section id="article-list" class="new-articles">
    </section>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.topic-button').click(function () {
        var topicName = $(this).data('topic-name');
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'mainapp:filter_articles' %}', // Use reverse URL lookup
            method: 'GET',
            data: {'topic_name': topicName},
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    console.error(response.error);
                    return;
                }
                // Here's an example
                $('#article-list').empty();  // Clear the current articles
                response.all_articles.forEach(function(article) {
                  $('#article-list').append('<div>' + article.body + '</div>');
            });
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```